# Given $a_n=\frac{1}{n} \sqrt[3]{n^{3}+n^{2}-n-1}$ find the smallest positive integer $k \geq2$ such that $a_2a_3\cdots a_k>4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> For a positive integer $n$, let
>
> $$a_n=\frac{1}{n} \sqrt[3]{n^{3}+n^{2}-n-1}$$
>
> Find the smallest positive integer $k \geq2$ such that $a_2a_3\cdots a_k>4$

I have just tried plugging in numbers so far

When $n=2$ I got $\frac{3^{\frac{2}{3}}}{2}$
When $n=3$ I got $\frac{2 \times 2^{\frac{2}{3}}}{3}$
When $n=4$ I got $\frac{1}{4} \times 3^{\frac{1}{3}} \times 5^{\frac{2}{3}}$

Now this is growing really slowly when multiplied together so this is obviously not the correct approach. Thanks for any help.

Edit tried going with a pattern the numbers made and I simplified it like this

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{k-1)(k+1)^2}(k-1)}{k}$$
Now I simplify and set up the ineqaulity
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{(2k^2)(k+1)^2}}{2k}>4$$

Comment: I'll try to analyze it.  in the meantime, I automated it and got $k=254$.

Comment: This was correct thanks

Comment: By the way, I got the same algebraic expression you got, though I don't think it is any simpler than automating the whole thing.  The quadratic answer posted below appears to yield $k=62$ which is not correct.

Comment: to be clear:  the algebraic formulation has clear value.  If you replace $4$ by $4,000,000,000$ then the raw automation is nearly useless.  Yet the raw automation has value too.  the algebra is messy and conducive to error.  It is a great comfort, at least, to be able to compare its results to a straight multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $n^3 + n^2 - n - 1 = \left(n^2-1\right)\left(n+1\right) = \left(n-1\right)\left(n+1\right)^2$

Notice then that the product $a_2a_3\cdots a_k = \left(\frac12\cdot\frac13\cdots \frac1k\right)\sqrt[3]{\left(2-1\right)\left(2+1\right)^2\left(3-1\right)\left(3+1\right)^2\cdots \left(k-1\right)\left(k+1\right)^2}$.

This equals $a_2a_3\cdots a_k = \frac1{k!}\sqrt[3]{\left(2-1\right)\left(2+1\right)^2\left(3-1\right)\left(3+1\right)^2\cdots \left(k-1\right)\left(k+1\right)^2}$.

For $\frac1{k!}\sqrt[3]{\left(2-1\right)\left(2+1\right)^2\left(3-1\right)\left(3+1\right)^2\cdots \left(k-1\right)\left(k+1\right)^2}$ to be greater than $4$, then $\sqrt[3]{\left(2-1\right)\left(2+1\right)^2\left(3-1\right)\left(3+1\right)^2\cdots \left(k-1\right)\left(k+1\right)^2}$ must exceed $4k!$. This is equivalent to saying that $\left(2-1\right)\left(2+1\right)^2\left(3-1\right)\left(3+1\right)^2\cdots \left(k-1\right)\left(k+1\right)^2$ must exceed $64\left(k!\right)^3$.

Now, notice that $\left(2-1\right)\left(2+1\right)^2\left(3-1\right)\left(3+1\right)^2\cdots \left(k-1\right)\left(k+1\right)^2$ rearranged is $\left(2-1\right)\left(3-1\right)\cdots \left(k-1\right)\left(2+1\right)^2\left(3+1\right)^2\cdots \left(k+1\right)^2 = \left(\left(k-1\right)!\right)\left(\left(k+1\right)!\right)^2$

Since $\left(k-1\right)! = \frac{k!}k$ and $\left(k+1\right)! = \left(k+1\right)k!$, we see that $\left(\left(k-1\right)!\right)\left(\left(k+1\right)!\right)^2 = \frac{\left(k+1\right)^2}{4k}\left(k!\right)^3$

Thus we need to find the smalled $k$ such that $\frac{\left(k+1\right)^2}{4k}\left(k!\right)^3 > 64\left(k!\right)^3$.

Divide each side by $\left(k!\right)^3$ to see that this simplifies to finding the smallest $k$ such that $\frac{\left(k+1\right)^2}k > 256$. This is equivalent to finding the smallest $k$ such that $k^2 - 254k + 1 > 0$.

Quadratic and you are done.

---

It is not unlikely that I made an error somewhere in here. Frankly, I need to look at it with fresh eyes later and hope to find the error. Also, my answer does not seem to match up with Lulu's answer. I am confident that the general approach was valid. Please point out the mistakes as you see them.

Comment: So the answer is $k=62$?  Perhaps I have botched the calculation (always a possibility) but I see the product out to the $62^{nd}$ term as just $2.52$

Comment: The telescoped expression for the product resolves (I believe) to the quadratic:  $k^2-254k+1>0$.  That gives $k=254$ which I see as the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that my answer would come out to be different. I will come back later with fresh eyes to find the mistake in here, provided that someone doesn't find it and point it out in the meantime.

Comment: My answer ($k = 62$) is two less than a power of $4$, as is the correct answer ($k = 254$). Likely, I just skipped multiplication by $4$ somewhere in my solution. It doesn't seem to be a major error; nevertheless, I cannot find it.

Comment: note inside when you use $(k+1)!$, you need to multiply $1 \times 2$, (it is from 3 to k+1),so the right one is :$\dfrac{(k+1)^2}{4k} >64$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

> Notice, $$\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2-n-1}$$$$=\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[3]{n^2(n+1)-(n+1)}$$ $$=\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2(n-1)}$$ $$=\frac{(n+1)^{2/3}(n-1)^{1/3}}{n}$$

Comment: Notice that $\sqrt[3]{\left(n+1\right)^2} \ne n+1$...

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. You are right. Thanks for observation.

Comment: I went a little different trying to make an inequality and using the pattern I got by plugging in numbers 

$\frac{\sqrt[3]{k-1)(k+1)^2}(k-1)}{k}$
Now I simplify and set up the ineqaulity
$\frac{\sqrt[3]{(2k^2)(k+1)^2}}{2k}>4$  Can I work with this also? Is this correct approach and where to go from here